# Horizontal constraints in iOS

Tags: ios, constraints

In my storyboard, my view controller has two container views as shown below

[image]
The second container view is it tone am having difficulty setting constraints for.

When I actually run the app, the text field, becomes very narrow. My horizontal constraints are obviously incorrect but I can't figure out the right settings.

Here what I currently have:

```
FilterIcon - trailing space to superview (right): 0
           - Align Center Y
           - Leading space to "Go": 16
           - Equal height to text box

Go Button  - align center Y
           - trailing space to filter icon: 16
           - leading space to text box: 8

Text Box   - leading space to superview (left): 0
           - trailing space to Go Button: 8
           - equal height to Filter icon
           - horizontal hugging priority: highest of 3 elements 751
```

I thought the text box would expand from the left margin until it reached the Go box which is set to the right based on the filter icon.

Instead I get this result:
[image]

What am I missing for the constraints?

Comment: Try auto constrains...

Comment: Try adding width constraint to textField. or instead add width constraint to filter icon and go button.

Comment: adding priority to leading of filter icon and "go" should be a quick fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about configuring like this?

Text Box

- leading space to superview (left): 0
- trailing space to Go Button: 8
- equal height to Filter icon
- horizontal compression priority: 752

Go Button

- align center Y
- trailing space to filter icon: 16
- leading space to text box: 8
- horizontal hugging priority: 251

Filter Icon

- horizontal hugging priority: 251
- Align Center Y
- Leading space to "Go": 16
- Equal height to text box

Here is my screenshot.

[image]

If you don't want to set priorities, you can just set width constraints for both Filter Icon and Go Button. For more information, there is very good tutorial about content hugging priority and compression resistance priority in [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64392/video-tutorial-beginning-auto-layout)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set both buttons' height equal to width. Then other space is left to the text field.

Comment: That gets it partly there as the filter icon and go button are in the right place but the text box is very narrow. I wonder if I must set a width for it?

Comment: Remove "horizontal hugging priority" of text field then it should work. Just curious why you set this constraint since it's against what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Give aspect ratio to the text field for its width and height and give center y to superview. This will definitely work. But make sure when you give aspect ratio, your text field is having the width you require.